# How to change the behaviour of enter key in UIwebview?

Tags: objective-c

i have a login page,in that after entering password when i hit 'enter' key login should occur.above said condition works in  browsers like chrome,firefox,safari but not in iphone simulator.In that when i hit 'enter' page reloads.plz help...

Answer (score 0):

The following code helps me to bring out what I want.

```
$('#password,#username').bind('keypress', function(e)
    {
         if(e.keyCode == 10)
         {
             e.preventDefault();
             $('#id_login').click();
         }

    });
```